# Google Cloud Platform not updating Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, google-cloud-platform

Six months ago, I created source code repository on Google Cloud Platform and successfully connected it to Android Studio.  Since then I have made changes to my source code and committed the changes using Android Studio.

In the Google Cloud Platform when viewing my source code, it only shows the initial date I created it.  However, in Android studio I can see history etc.

Shouldn't I be able to view source code control information, dates, notes, etc. In Google Cloud Platform?  Seeing everything with the original date, makes me think things aren't being stored or updated, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue.  When I do a "commit" from Android Studio, it is only a local commit.  That I have to do a PUSH via Git, to update Google Cloud Platform.